# Making equal top(or bottom) margins between blocks in multi-column layout

Tags: html, css

I have a problem - i have to do 3-column layout of the web page with equal bottom and side margins between article excerpts and the problem is that the excerpts have different heights. What can i do in this situation if i'll use the floats and if i'll use the flexbox?

```
<div class="articles-wrap">
            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/h9hu35mq1/post-img-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/442bx1suh/post-img-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus quis neque nisi. Pellentesque non vestibulum ex.</p>
            </article>

            <article class="last-in-row">
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/rtrrlqr7t/post-img-3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/rtrrlqr7t/post-img-3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>

            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/h9hu35mq1/post-img-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>

            <article class="last-in-row">
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/442bx1suh/post-img-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/h9hu35mq1/post_img_1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/442bx1suh/post-img-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="last-in-row">
                <div>
                <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/rtrrlqr7t/post_img_3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>This is blog post title</h3>
                <p>Phasellus in tincidunt velit. Etiam fermentum fringilla tristique. Aenean posuere aliquam interdum. Sed dignissim turpis eget leo ultricies ultricies. Sed et felis leo, eget dapibus massa. Etiam volutpat vehicula dolor, vel placerat odio posuere non.</p>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Sample code is [here](http://codepen.io/Leo240/pen/qbLpgb)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirement you could choose the following options
1. give equal height to article and give overflow-y:scroll so that a if the text exceeds the height of article a scroll will appear
2. If you don't want scroll and you know what is the maximum possible length of the text then adjust the height of article accordingly or give a a text limit

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it can be done with flexbox module, but only if you know the final number of child blocks (article excerpts in this case) and set the height of the parent block.